# How to deploy an app from circleCI to aws eb

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli, circleci

Currently I have a circle.yml which looks like :

```
   dependencies:
     pre:
- rvm install 2.3.3
- sudo pip install -U pip setuptools
- sudo apt-get install python-dev
- sudo pip install awsebcli
- gem install bundler
- bundle install

  general:
   branches:
        only:
         - st5-ci

  deployment:
    production:
    branch: xt5-ci
commands:
  - eb init
  - eb deploy --profile default
```

However the eb init command is stuck forever and doesnt move forward, and if I try to run the yml without init, eb deploy fails.

I am pretty new to aws tools and cli, can someone please help on this?

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/var/log/eb-activity.log`?

Comment: Now the error is : ERROR: TypeError :: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'  on running eb deploy. And about eb-activity, not sure i have access to this as it is running in a container on circleci

Comment: If you are able to run `eb init`, you should be able to run `eb ssh` and access the log file. Alternatively, you can run `eb logs` and get the same information.

Comment: eb logs also fails with the same error.

Comment: It took me ages to get all this right, I wrote a tutorial on the entire deployment process: https://kevingoedecke.me/2018/03/12/circleci-2-0-beanstalk-example-tutorial/ maybe this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`eb init` creates a file at location - `./elasticbeanstalk/config.yml`. Perhaps you can try adding that manually and see if it works .

It's content would be like -

```
branch-defaults:
  develop:
    environment: yourdevelopbranch
deploy:
  artifact: build/yourartifact.war
global:
  application_name: your-application-name
  default_ec2_keyname: ec2-key-pair-name
  default_platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.4.3 running Ruby 2.2 (Puma)
  default_region: us-east-1
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: git
```

`eb init` needs some inputs. Looks at - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-init.html

OR

you can try `eb init --profile profilename` . So for default profile it will `eb init --profile default`